# mybatis not returning all the rows on lazy fetch

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

My java application when using mybatis (3.4.4) to query oracle back end is not returning all the rows when using lazy load.

Essentially,

- when I query my database using some SQL tool (like oracle Sql Developer) I get 4000 results
- when I query using **selectCursor** which leads to lazy load `conn.selectCusror(query)` I only get 560 result!
- when I query using **selectList** which will fetch all result at once `conn.selectList(query)` I am getting 4000 results (matches with database)

**Note**: A Cursor offers the same results as a List, except it fetches data lazily using an Iterator. [Documentation](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSession.html#selectCursor(java.lang.String))

This is how I am counting the number of records

```
Cursor<Object> cur = conn.selectCursor(query) ; // query definition is written below
int count =0;
for(Object ob : cur){
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

**QUERY**

```
<select id="query" fetchSize="20000" resultType="java.util.Map" >
    select distinct code from my CODES_VIEW
</select>
```

Can someone please advise why selectCursor is not giving all the 4000 results

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. I would look into it if you could provide a small project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) which demonstrates the different behavior between `selectList()` and `selectCursor()`. It should contain the minimum data for reproduction as well.

Comment: Hey Thanks for trying to help. I was finally able to find the solution. Have posted it as well

Answer (score 0):

After spending days I found this solution:

My result set from the query contains a row (561) which have null values in its column. This shouldn't be a problem as I can have null values in the columns I fetched . In this case `code` column has value `null` at row 561. 
When fetching records via `selectCursor` (lazy method of fetching data) mybatis believes it is end of record when all the columns are null in the fetched row.

> MyBatis, by default, returns null when all the columns of a returned
>   row are NULL. When this setting is enabled, MyBatis returns an empty
>   instance instead. Note that it is also applied to nested results (i.e.
>   collectioin and association). Since: 3.4.2
>   https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html

However, you won't face this problem when you use `selectList` as all the records are fetched at once and cursor doesn't keep on checking on how does the next fetched records look like .

Hence the solution is to put the below setting in the mybatis config.xml

```
<setting name="returnInstanceForEmptyRow" value="true" />
```

Comment: Glad to know you solved the problem! FYI, this issue was [reported](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1653) a while ago and was fixed in version 3.5.3.